# Does a django query save its result after it's been called?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to determine whether or not a simple caching trick will actually be useful. I know Django querysets are lazy to improve efficiency, but I'm wondering if they save the result of their query after the data has been called.

For instance, if I have two models:

```
class Klass1(models.Model):  
    k2 = models.ForeignKey('Klass2')

class Klass2(models.Model):
    # Model Code ...
    @property
    def klasses(self):
        self.klasses = Klass1.objects.filter(k2=self)
        return self.klasses
```

And I call `klass_2_instance.klasses[:]` somewhere, then the database is accessed and returns a query. I'm wondering if I call `klass_2_instance.klasses` again, will the database be accessed a second time, or will the django query save the result from the first call?

Comment: Did I ever mention that `klass` instead of `class` looks horrible? `cls` is the way to go IMO if the name is used in a context where `class` would cause an error.

Comment: No worries, I just used klass here as an arbitrary name. This isn't an actual model I'm using, just code for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will not cache it for you.

Instead of Klass1.objects.filter(k2=self), you could just do self.klass1_set.all().
Because Django always create a set in the many side of 1-n relations.

I guess this kind of cache is complicated because it should remember all filters, excludes and order_by used. Although it could be done using any well designed hash, you should at least have a parameter to disable cache.

If you would like any cache, you could do:

```
class Klass2(models.Model):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._klass1_cache = None
    super(Klass2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def klasses(self):
    if self._klass1_cache is None:
      # Here you can't remove list(..) because it is forcing query execution exactly once.
      self._klass1_cache = list(self.klass1_set.all())
    return self._klass1_cache
```

This is very useful when you loop many times in all related objects. For me it often happens in template, when I need to loop more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

This query isn't cached by Django.

The *forwards* FK relationship - ie given a `Klass` object `klass`, doing `klass.k2` - *is* cached after the first lookup. But the reverse, which you're doing here - and which is actually usually spelled `klass2.klass_set.all()` - is *not* cached.

You can easily memoize it:

```
@property
def klasses(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_klasses'):
        self._klasses = self.klass_set.all()
    return self._klasses
```

(Note that your existing code won't work, as you're overriding the method `klasses` with an attribute.)

Comment: Interestingly enough, since I'm using the property decorator, it actually does work. Python assumes that I'm putting the data into the variable `klasses`, and replaces the reference to the decorated method with a reference to the new value. However, like you said, that won't actually cache the data in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using johnny-cache if you want transparent caching of querysets.